# What is an unupvote and why does it cost more rep points than a downvote?

Tags: support, voting

My first downvote was reported as an unupvote in my rep score. It cost 10 points. I thought that was normal until I received another downvote and discovered that it cost only 2 rep points. What is the difference between a downvote and an unupvote? I Googled it and got nothing.

Comment: Take your cursor on those upvote, downvote symbols; you'ld get what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An "unupvote" is the removal of an upvote, and consequently removes the rep gain associated with that vote. In my experience they are fairly rare. They are distinct from a down vote (though the effect on a question's score is essentially the same if you neglect that the voter had previously increased the questions score).

Users are allow to cancel a vote during a brief window after casting it or after an intervening edit. The user may have changed their mind becuase they read some other answers or didn't like a clarification in the comments or they may not have liked an edit that you (or someone else) made to your post after they initially voted.

[When you reach 1000 rep you'll gain the ability to click on post scores and see a up/down breakdown as well as the net.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) Under those conditions the difference is clear.

Comment: Thank you. That clears up my confusion.